# geting information from a xml string

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.eve-central.com/api/quicklook?typeid=34&usesystem=30002053");
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        myResponse.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
        IEnumerable<string> prices = from price in result.Descendants("order") select (string)price.Attribute("price");

    }
```

`result.Descendants("order")` shows an error

> "The type 'char' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in generic type
>   or method"

how can i take all the prices from buy_orders in to a double array  ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to apply a Linq to XML method to a string; it doesn't work that way, you have to parse the XML into an `XDocument` first.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.eve-central.com/api/quicklook?typeid=34&usesystem=30002053");
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    XDocument doc;
    using (WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
        doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
    }
    IEnumerable<string> prices = from price in doc.Descendants("order") select (string)price.Attribute("price");

}
```